# How to get a value between 2 and -2 with a driver having 2 variables having z rotation of camera and the z rotation of object in view?

Tags: animation, camera, drivers

I am trying to animate a character which require driver value of range -2 to 2 when the character rotates his head and also when camera rotates around the character.
I am having trouble with the expression, if i rotate the head in only y or x axis, z axis is also changing.

Here is what i want to achieve:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/wvH90.jpg
Please watch to make sense of what im trying to say.

Here is what i tried.
[image: Driver]

Comment: *"Z axis is also changing"* - a rotation property in **N**umbers panel is changing, or visually the head rotates along Z axis? If the latter, perhaps the object is parented to another object, or perhaps it's (or your view) is not aligned with the axes, or perhaps the mesh is rotated inside the object and you need to press CTRL+A and choose *apply rotations*?

Comment: Solved! Turns out the camera rotation was set to xyz euler and driver had quaternion. So i set it to xyz euler in driver and that solved it.

Comment: @MarkusvonBroady Thanks anyway for trying to help